# "De" vs "du" in the case of another noun preceding a noun

Tags: grammaire

So for example, "I have some back problems", has a noun "back" to describe the main noun "problems". It is translated as "*J'ai des problèmes de dos.*"

Why is it "***de*** dos" and not "***du*** dos"?

I thought "*problèmes du dos*" makes more sense since it would directly translate to "problems of the back".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Problèmes de dos*** can be considered as a whole that describes the problems that affect backs in general, not someone's back in particular. That's the reason why we don't say *problèmes du dos*. You states that it translates to "I have some problems of the back" but that doesn't sound right in English either. "Back problems" seems closer to "problems of back(s)".

There are many expressions built that way:

> - *J'ai des problèmes de coeur.*
> - *J'ai des problèmes de santé.*
> - *J'ai des problèmes de riche(s).*
> - *J'ai des problèmes de trésorerie.*
> - *J'ai des problèmes de wifi.*
> - *J'ai des problèmes de mathématiques (à résoudre).*

Should you want to specifically talk about your own back, you can also say:

> - *J'ai des problèmes **au** dos* (implicitly *à mon dos*).

Answer (score 0):

La façon de traiter ce concept est différente en français.

Une explication se trouve au « **I A 6. b) β)** » de l'entrée « de¹ » dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) ; du moins je crois que c'est la bonne et cette analyse particulière que fait le dictionnaire semble très convaincante.

> I.− De prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent.
>   A.− De exprime le point de départ.
>   6. Le point de départ est un tout dont on tire une partie.
>   b) Subst. + de. De a une valeur partitive, proche de celle de l'article partitif. Cf. de² et des II (en parlant d'une partie, d'un ensemble, d'un élément d'un tout).
>   β) [En parlant d'un tout nombrable, en partic. un subst. coll.]
>
> - Une troupe d'enfants; un couple de rossignols; des escouades de motocyclistes. L'âpre essaim des corbeaux voraces.  (Hugo, Légende,t. 3, 1877, p. 30)

Essayons de clarifier cela  autant que possible.

**I** **« De » prend une valeur sémantique en fonction de « problème »**.
**A** **« De » exprime le point de départ ;** *les problèmes ont tous un contexte, des éléments desquels ils sont essentiellement issus (problème d'argent, de logement, de déplacement, de santé, …, de dos, …).*
**6** **Le point de départ est un tout dont on tire une partie.** *Du tout dont quelques éléments sont donnés ci-dessus on tire « dos ».*
**b)** **« De » a une valeur partitive, proche de celle de l'article partitif.** « des *problèmes associés au dos », pas tous, un peu comme* « des *tasses de café », pas tout le café*
**β) [En parlant d'un tout nombrable, en partic. un subst. coll.]** *Les problèmes sont des choses que l'on dénombre, évidemment ; on oppose cela à* « **α) [En parlant d'un tout partageable] »**, *voir ci-dessous. (Le tout d'un ananas n'est pas nombrable, c'est une masse, de même pour une sole.)*

- [Le compl. est un subst. non déterminé] Tranches d'ananas; filets de sole; branche d'arbre.
- [Le compl. est un subst. déterminé] La façade nord du transept de la cathédrale; marcher sur la pointe des pieds.